# Different Minimum Order Amounts Based on Shipping Zone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am trying to implement a different minimum order requirement based on the shipping zone in woocommerce and I can't seem to get this to work. The $49.99 minimum still seems to be in effect despite someone's address being located in Zone 3.

```
// MINIMUM CART AMOUNT FOR CHECKOUT

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {
    $zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'zone_id', 3 );
    // Only run it in  Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        // Get cart shipping packages
        $shipping_packages =  WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

        // Get the WC_Shipping_Zones instance object for the first package
        $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );
        $zone_id   = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID
        $zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name

        // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
        $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

         // HERE Set minimum cart total amount (for Zone 3 and for other zones)
        $min_total = $zone == 3 ? 99.99 : 49.99;


        // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
        if( $total <= $min_total  ) {
            // Display an error message
            wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . sprintf(
                __("A minimum total purchase amount of %s is required to checkout."),
                wc_price($min_total)
            ) . '<strong>', 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo the values in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$zone = WC_Shipping_Zone Object

```php
$zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'zone_id', 3 );

...

// HERE Set minimum cart total amount (for Zone 3 and for other zones)
$min_total = $zone == 3 ? 99.99 : 49.99;
```

> ERROR: Object of class WC_Shipping_Zone could not be converted to int

here is the error in my opinion, you compare the object as an integer, while this should be $zone_id

does this solve the problem?

```php
$min_total = $zone_id == 3 ? 99.99 : 49.99;
```

Comment: It did! Wow, didn't even see that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
// MINIMUM CART AMOUNT FOR CHECKOUT

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {
    $zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by ( 'zone_name', "1" . 'zone_name', "2" . 'zone_name' , "3" );

    // Only run it in  Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        // Get cart shipping packages
        $shipping_packages =  WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

        // Get the WC_Shipping_Zones instance object for the first package
        $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );
        $zone_id   = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID
        $zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name

        // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
        $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

         // HERE Set minimum cart total amount (for Zone 1,2,3 and for other zones)
       // $min_total = $zone_name == ״1״ ? 99.99 : 200.0;
$min_total = 200;
if  ($zone_name == "2") $min_total = 300;
if ($zone_name == "3") $min_total = 350;

        // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
   if( $total <= $min_total  ) {
            // Display an error message
 wc_add_notice(   sprintf(
                __("minimum order is - %s "),
                wc_price( $min_total)
            )  , 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you expand your answer (apart from the code comments) to better explain how the snippet could help with the issue at hand?